# Problemas para insertar datos de un array

Tags: php, mysql, array, bucle-for

Hola Buenas noches me gustaria saber mas o menos que estoy haciendo mal en esta función que hice para insertar una cantidad de registros dependiendo del periodo colocado por ejemplo si el periodo viene con un valor 5 se insertan 5 veces el mismo registro con un id autoincrement por ahora ya funciona.

pero ahora lo que intento hacer es que por medio de un select con la numeración de los meses del año  si selecciono febrero que tiene como valor "2" y con el periodo en "5" quiero guardar en la columna meses los 5 registros pero con los 5 meses que empiecen a partir de febrero que tiene como valor "2".

insertando dentro de mi tabla los registros de la siguiente forma.

```
id,nombre,meses
1,prueba,febrero
2,prueba,marzo
3,prueba,abril
4,prueba,mayo
5,prueba,junio


function guardar(){
    global $mysqli;
    
    $id                   = (!empty($_REQUEST["id"]) ? $_REQUEST["id"] : "");
    $periodo              = (!empty($_REQUEST["periodo"]) ? $_REQUEST["periodo"] : 0);
    $nombre               = (!empty($_REQUEST["nombre"]) ? $_REQUEST["nombre"] : "prueba");
    $mes                  = (!empty($_REQUEST["mes"]) ? $_REQUEST["mes"] : 0); //este es el valor que viene de un select con los meses
    
    $Mes = array('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6',
   '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12');
   
  for($i=0;$i< $periodo;$i++){
  if(is_array($mes)){
   foreach ($mes as $value) {
    echo $value = $i;
    }
   }
    $query = "  INSERT INTO tabla (nombre,meses) 
            VALUES('".$nombre."','".$mes."')";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);
    }
    if ($result == true ) {
        echo 1; 
    } else {
        echo 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: La query, donde utilizas $mes, esta fuera del foreach donde defines la variable $mes.

Answer (score 0):

Es tan sencillo como que el bucle for, la i la inicialices con el valor del mes que selecciona el usuario en el select y el bucle se repita el número de veces indicado por el usuario en en el select periodo.
También, dentro de cada iteración es donde tienes que hacer el INSERT y no fuera como lo tienes ahora

Sería algo así:

```
for ($i = $mes; $i < $mes + $periodo; $i++) {
    /* Usamos "$i < $mes + $periodo ya que el máximo de $i va a ser el mes por el que se empieza más el periodo indicado
    En este punto hay que tener cuidado ya que tendrás que hacer la comprobación de si se pasa de 12, ya que si por ejemplo el usuario selecciona por ejemplo noviembre
     y  un periodo de por ejemplo 4, nos iriamos a meses inexistentes (11, 12, 13, 14 ) */

    $query = "INSERT INTO tabla (nombre,meses) VALUES('" . $nombre . "','" . $mes . "')";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);
}
```

Ten en cuenta que eso es solo un ejemplo para hacerte ver como podrías hacerlo, en ningún caso deberías de copiarlo y pegarlo porque seguramente el código requiera alguna modificación por tu parte y porque haciendolo tu, será más facil que lo entiendas y que en un futuro lo puedas hacer solo.

Comment: y en caso si quiero que me envie un mes distinto a mi variable $mes iniciando desde el mes indicado por el select y por cada vez que se ejecuta el insert?